# Showing that $F \times G \in A^I$ respects composition in $I$, where $A$ is additive cat.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, additive-categories

If $i \xrightarrow{g} j \xrightarrow{f} k$ in $I$, then

$F(i) \xrightarrow{F(g)} F(j) \xrightarrow{F(f)} F(k) \\
G(i) \xrightarrow{G(g)} G(j) \xrightarrow{G(f)} G(k)$

in $A$.  And since $A$ is additive, we have $F(i) \times G(i)$ existing in $A$ and thus:

$F(i) \times G(i) \xrightarrow{\pi^F_i} F(i) \to F(j) \to F(k) \\
F(i) \times G(i) \xrightarrow{\pi^G_i} G(i) \to G(j) \to G(k) 
$

So that considering the product $F(k) \times G(k)$, there is a unique map $\alpha : F(i) \times G(i) \to F(k) \times G(k)$ such that:

$$
\pi^F_k \alpha = F(f) \circ F(g) \circ \pi_i^F \\
\pi^G_k \alpha = G(f) \circ G(g) \circ \pi_i^G
$$

But how do I get that $\alpha(f\circ g) = (F\times G)(f \circ g) = (F \times G)(f) \circ (F\times G)(g)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $\alpha$ is the unique map having the properties you mentioned. So, you just have to show that both $(F\times G)(f \circ g)$ and  $(F \times G)(f) \circ (F\times G)(g)$ have those properties to conclude that they are equal.

By definition, $(F\times G)(f \circ g)$ satisfy these properties. For $(F \times G)(f) \circ (F\times G)(g)$, we have $$\pi_k^F \circ (F \times G)(f) \circ (F\times G)(g)=F(f) \circ \pi_j^F \circ (F\times G)(g)=F(f) \circ F(g) \circ \pi_i^F$$ and similarly for $G$.

Comment: I know that, but I'm having trouble showing that.  It seems like there's no 'plugging in' any where.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give details.

Comment: How on Earth did you get $\pi_k^F \circ (F\times G)(f) = F(f) \circ \pi_j^F$?

Comment: Because $(F\times G)(f)$  is by definition the unique map that has this property.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see that, even though it should be obvious :)

Comment: Well look at my answer for your previous question, or look at what you wrote about $\alpha$ being the unique map such that... but in that case do this construction with $F(f)$ instead of $F(f\circ g)$.

Comment: I have $\exists ! \beta : F(i) \times G(i) \to F(j) \times G(j)$ st $\pi_j^F \circ \beta = F(f) \circ \pi_i^F$

Comment: That's what I used for the last equallity. Do the same thing for $j\to k$ to get $\pi_k^F \circ (F\times G)(f) = F(f) \circ \pi_j^F$.